# How to get Chrome Logged in User information

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, google-signin

I am developing a Web application where I am making users sign-in with Google. Just to add a courtesy, I want to show them their email if they are already logged in to Chrome. How can I fetch if user is logged in to Chrome and what is his email?

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to register an app with the [google console](https://console.developers.google.com/). You will then have to use the [`googleapis`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) in the browser to log in as well and after the user has given your app the permissions you can fetch their details.

A lot more information here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow